# How to Install Bokeh in Pydev, Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, bokeh

Is it possible to install Bokeh, the data visualization package to Pydev, Eclipse without changing the interpreter to Anaconda. I have the current interpreter as python 2.7 and have some very important libraries added. I am pretty scared about changing the interpreter.

Any solutions friends?

Yedurag

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh is available from PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bokeh

You should just be able to use pip: `pip install bokeh`

Comment: I need to install all the dependencies too. right?...Does pip work in pydev...sorry if I am wrong..I tried pip...Its not working

Comment: pip normally installs all the required dependencies, I'm not sure if there is some different behavior with PyDev, or if PyDev offers some entirely different mechanism for installing libraries.

Comment: I will add, one nice thing about Anaconda is that it installs entirely self contained in its own directory and does not touch or affect your system python at all. So you could try installing your other projects into an Anaconda environment and just delete it with no repercussion if they did not work for some reason.

Comment: http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration.html#eclipse-pydev  Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Well, I was suggesting you could easily try out things outside of Eclipse first, if that makes you more comfortable.